# Gutenberg - remove / add blocks with custom script

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I’m currently testing the new Gutenberg plugin with my own developed theme and plugin.
My theme has a custom meta box with an action for the user. Once the user click this action the post content is completely deleted and a new ‘custom’ content is added to the default tinyMce editor.

***Example***: tinymce.get(“content”).setContent(“my custom content”);

This of course does not work anymore with the new Guteberg Editor and I’m struggeling to find a solution.

So Basically what I’m trying to do is to remove all block/content from the gutenberg editor and add a new block (text) with my custom content via javascript. Does anyone have any hint to point me in the right direction?

Comment: the gutenberg blocks are stored in a data store, here's a good primer on that https://riad.blog/2018/06/07/efficient-client-data-management-for-wordpress-plugins/ that might lead to an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's probably a simpler way to do this, and if there isn't you should open an issue on the Gutenberg GH issue tracker ( the API is not set in stone ).

**Because the API is not set in stone, this answer may be useless when it's finally done and merged. The first and best place to ask GB questions is on GitHub**

You can eliminate all blocks using this:

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).resetBlocks([]);
```

You can then create a new block programmatically:

```
let block = wp.blocks.createBlock( 'core/paragraph' );
```

Add text to it:

```
block.attributes.content.push( 'hello world' );
```

And insert it like this:

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).insertBlocks( block );
```

---

**On further inspection, there's a simpler method:**

```js
let block = wp.blocks.createBlock( 'core/paragraph', { content: 'test' } );
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).insertBlocks( block );
```

Comment: The solution is deprecated. Use 'core/block-editor'...

Comment: Hence the bolded note that the API was not final, I've edited the question to use `block-editor` though, and the code still worked but told users what to change