# How to render core component inside edit() within custom registered block in Gutenberg?

Tags: block-editor

How to render core block such as `core/columns` inside custom registered block in Gutenberg?

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/305935) as an example, but I don't really understand how to render it inside my own block with `edit()`.

I thought of using something like `createBlock('core/columns')`, but it gives an error on render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [components](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src) inside your block. However, to insert a block inside your block you need to make use of the editor component [**Innerblocks**](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/editor/src/components/inner-blocks). Using it you can set a predefined template which includes certain blocks in a specific order. Or you can set allowed blocks that can be added by the user.

For example, the `columns block` uses Innerblocks component and includes the `column block` using the template prop, which uses again Innerblocks to allow any kind of block to be added inside each column.